# Создать через цикл for элементы DOM дерева

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i in data.results) { //data.results состоит из 10 объектов 
    $('.container').append('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="row"></div>');
```

В container добавляется 10 элементов с классом wrapper это норм, но как сделать так чтобы в wrapper добавлялся только один row?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор `$('.wrapper')` выбирает **все** элементы с классом *wrapper* на странице.

Вместо него, нужно создать элемент с классом *wrapper* и добавить `row` непосредственно в него, и только потом добавить все в `container`.

Конечный код может выглядеть так:

```
for (var i in data.results) { //data.results состоит из 10 объектов 
    $('<div class="wrapper"></div>') // создаем wrapper
        .append('<div class="row"></div>') // добавляем в него row
        .appendTo('.container'); // добавляем wrapper в container
```